# How can I write a regular expression to detect a word within parentheses? Mine doesn't work. (Example given)

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to detect the word *apple* if the word apple appears anywhere within curly parentheses (`{...}`). These parentheses can be nested. So `she ate an apple` should not match, while `she ate a {food:apple}` should and `she stole my {foods{apple}}` should.

I wrote `/\{[^{}]*?(?:\{apple?\})*?[^{}]*?\}/i`, but this matches *anything* that appears within curly parentheses, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

**EDIT**: I am using Ruby. 
In the following example:

```
This line with apple in it shouldn't match.
This line with ${the.word.apple} in it should.
This line with ${something.else} should not match.
```

only line 2 should match. My problem is that I am getting a false match on line 3.

Comment: This looks like JavaScript, but can you indicate which programming language you are using? Regex parsers vary from language to language.

Comment: @GregBughardt I was unaware of this, sorry. I'm using Ruby. http://rubular.com/ has a Regex tester for Ruby. I will update my post with an example of strings that should and shouldn't match and my language to improve the question.

Comment: Should `{snapple}` match?

Comment: Actually, I'd also add the following line as an example: `This line with ${something.else} apple ${something.else} should not match.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\{[^}]*?apple[^}]*\}
```

#### [Ruby RegEx Demo](http://rubular.com/r/LYy1cPSbJx)

Answer (score 0):

Most straightforward way I could find:

```
\{[^{]*apple\}
```

i.e., a single open `{`, optionally followed by *not* `}`, and the phrase `apple}`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if I got it right, the word "apple" can be anywhere inside `{}`, so the right regex is:

```
/\{[^\}]*apple.*\}/
```